# Prepend list-item using JQuery with close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

### I want to prepend new list item with checkbox, input box and close button when i click in "+ List item" and by press enter in input box. Like: Google Keep checked item event is work in notes.

> In this code when i press enter on input box it works fine and it also
> prepend new list item when i click on "+ List item". But here, I am
> facing some problem When i add new list item on click "+ list item"
> and then I click in list item anywhere then it again add new list
> item.
>
> I want to make list like list item. I want it add list item when i
> press enter or when click on "+ List Item" only.

```js
$( "#list_item" ).keypress(function(e) {
  var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if(key == '13'){
    $('#list_item').prepend('<li><input type="checkbox" name="checkb"><input type="text" name="txt" class="inpt"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ml-2">&times;</span></li><br>');
  }
});

$("#add-list").click(function(){
  $('#add-list').prepend('<li><input type="checkbox" name="checkb"><input type="text" name="txt" class="inpt" ><span aria-hidden="true" class="ml-2">&times;</span></li><br>');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
   
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row" id="note" style="display: block">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="cursor:pointer;">
          <div class="card mt-5 popup popuptext" onclick="myFunction()">
            
              <div class="card-body">
                    
                      <p class="card-text mt-4">
                        <ul id="list_item" class="list-unstyled ml-3">
                          <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkb"><input type="text" name="txt" class="inpt" ><span aria-hidden="true" class="ml-2">&times;</span></li><br>
                          <li id="add-list" style="cursor:pointer;"> + List item </li>
                        </ul>
                      </p>

              </div>
             
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `prepend()` you are actually adding your checkbox row inside the `add-list` li element. So basically you are making the `add-list` li element a bigger target each time you click on it.

Place your `add-list` element outside the `ul` and use `append()`.

```js
$( "#my-list" ).keypress( function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if ( key == '13' ) {
        addListItem()
    }
});

$( "#add-list" ).click( function() {
  addListItem();
});

function addListItem() {
    $('#my-list').append('<li><input type="checkbox"><input type="text"><span>&times;</span></li>');
}
```

```css
ul { 
  list-style: none; 
  padding: 0; 
}

button { margin-top: 10px; }

li { margin-bottom: 10px; }

li span, 
li input[type="text"] { 
  margin-left: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="my-list">
    <li><input type="checkbox"><input type="text"><span>&times;</span></li>
</ul>
<button id="add-list"> + List item </button>
```

Comment: If this answer works for you please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and possibly vote it up. Thank you in advance!